# Understanding Simple Inverse Distribution

Tags: distributions, cumulative-distribution-function

I know this is quite basic, but I fail to see where my mistake with the following simple example from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution) is.

\begin{align*}
G(y) &= \Pr(Y \leq y) \\
&= \Pr \left (X \geq \frac{1}{y} \right) \\
&= 1 - \Pr\left(X < \frac{1}{y} \right) \\
&= 1 - F\left(\frac{1}{y} \right)
\end{align*}

What I don't understand is, why does first CDF, i.e. $G(y) = \Pr(Y \leq y)$, say "*smaller or equal*", while the second CDF, i.e. $F\left(\frac{1}{y} \right)= \Pr\left(X < \frac{1}{y} \right)$, says "*strictly smaller*"?

Shouldn't they both have the same definition, i.e. "smaller or equal", as they're both just a normal CDF? Can you please explain to me what I'm missing?

Comment: It is assumed that $X$ is a continuous random variable with a density and so $\Pr(X=x) = 0$ for all $x$. It follows that $\Pr\left(X < \frac{1}{y} \right) = \Pr\left(X \leq \frac{1}{y} \right) = F\left(\frac{1}{y} \right)$

Comment: I see, thanks a lot, that makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$
\Pr\Big(X \ge \frac{1}{y} \Big) = 1 - \Pr\Big(X < \frac{1}{y} \Big)
$$

it would be contradictory if you had "$=$" on both sides of the equation. Moreover, as noticed in the comment, for continuous random variable $\Pr(X = x) = 0$ so it doesn't really matter.